# how to write a method (decompose) that takes as input a string and returns the array of characters that compose the string in java?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, decomposition

Hint:

The expression s.charAt(i) returns the character at position i of the string s.

Test:

```
String word = "Hello";
System.out.println("The word \""+word+"\" decomposes as "+Arrays.toString(decomposeString(word)));
```

Result:

The word "Hello" decomposes as [h, e, l, l, o]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.toCharArray()` method for this.

**Example**

```
String str = "Hello";
char[] ch = str.toCharArray();
```

[More information](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-tochararray)